# C++ error constructor parameter

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i'm playing around with inheritance. I'm completely baffled by the compiler
error i'm getting and looking it up it seems completely unrelated to what i'm trying
to do which is simply initialize my class.

here are the errors:

```
    In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
student.h: In constructor ‘Student::Student(std::string, int, std::string, double)’:
student.h:13:3: error: class ‘Student’ does not have any field named ‘gnu_dev_major’
student.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&)’:
student.h:25:8: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘os << "Name\011: "’
student.h:25:8: note: candidates are:
student.h:24:16: note: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&)
student.h:24:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char [8]’ to ‘const Student&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
student.h:25:32: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
student.h:26:8: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘os << "Age\011: "’
student.h:26:8: note: candidates are:
student.h:24:16: note: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&)
student.h:24:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char [7]’ to ‘const Student&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
student.h:26:30: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
student.h:27:8: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘os << "Major\011: "’
student.h:27:8: note: candidates are:
student.h:24:16: note: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&)
student.h:24:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char [9]’ to ‘const Student&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
student.h:27:34: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
student.h:28:8: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘os << "GPA\011: "’
student.h:28:8: note: candidates are:
student.h:24:16: note: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&)
student.h:24:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char [7]’ to ‘const Student&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
student.h:28:30: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:2: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
```

whats confusing me is the very first error i'm getting:

> student.h: In constructor ‘Student::Student(std::string, int,
>   std::string, double)’: student.h:13:3: error: class ‘Student’ does not
>   have any field named ‘gnu_dev_major’

here is my code:

```
  1 #ifndef STUDENT_H
  2 #define STUDENT_H
  3 
  4 #include <iostream>
  5 #include <string>
  6 #include "person.h"
  7 
  8 class Student : public Person {
  9         friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &,const Student &);
 10 public:
 11         Student(std::string name, int age, std::string m="undecided", double gpa=0.0) :
 12                 Person::Person(name,age),
 13                 major(m),
 14                 gpa(gpa)
 15         {}
 16 
 17 
 18 
 19 protected:
 20         double gpa;
 21         std::string major;
 22 };
 23 
 24 std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os,const Student &s){
 25         os << "Name\t: " << s.name << std::endl;
 26         os << "Age\t: " << s.age << std::endl;
 27         os << "Major\t: " << s.major << std::endl;
 28         os << "GPA\t: " << s.gpa << std::endl;
 29 }
 30 
 31 #endif
```

also if anyone has a pointer as to what might be going wrong in my overloaded
operator << help with that is also appreciated =).

Comment: Just a guess - does one of the gnu headers `#define` the macro `major` to something? If you change your class's `major` variable to something with a different name, does the problem go away?

Comment: `Person::Person(name,age)` is wrong (I think), certainly `Person(name,age)` is the usual way to call a base class constructor.

Comment: user1118321: omg that actually worked. Although its strange, I declared a string called major in main and that worked just fine. What could the issue have been?

Comment: john: Person::Person(name,age) is the same as Person(name,age). Your right though, i prolly don't need the scope resolution.

Comment: @ritual_code See [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=130601) (and [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17130)). On your system, `<iostream>` (and/or `<string>`) indirectly includes `sys/sysmacros.h` which contains an evil `#define major(dev) gnu_dev_major(dev)` (so `major(m)` gets corrupted but not e.g. `std::string major;`). Apparently this can be avoided in C mode with compiler option `-ansi` but that doesn't work in C++ mode. I find it a bit hard to swallow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your overloaded << operator as friend inside your class:

Inside your Student class declare it as follows:

```
class Student {
    // rest of code
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os,const Student &s);
}
```

Comment: It also needs to be declared inline.

Comment: You mean implement it in the class? I declare the operator<< inside my class as a friend, I've done it before succesfully

Comment: You should'nt need to implement in class, I just noticed, you need to `return os;` inside your `<<` implementation

Comment: No, unfortunately that didnt help =(

Comment: I included the return os and made it inline, so far the "student.h:33:8: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘os << "Major\011: " is still a factor

Comment: Also the compiler is telling me that 'endl' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: This [code](http://ideone.com/wfc3nN) works for me. I renamed major to major1. Seems like you are facing this error for major : http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17130. Honestly I don't have any idea about this because your code worked fine in Visual Studio C++ without renaming major.

Comment: Yeah, it was a surprise. Still don't get whats going on with the operator<< i'll try googling it thanks for all the help!

Comment: @ritual_code It's need to be inline because you've put it in a header file. You could just add the keyword `inline` or you could declare it in class. None of this is related to the error you are facing though.