# C++ iostream isn't working properly

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

using g++ compiler to compile the following program:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include "student.h"
  3 #include <string>
  4 
  5 using namespace std;
  6 
  7 int main(){
  8         string major("hello");
  9         Student s("Henry Markov", 21), s2("Wallace Piirish", 22, "Computer Science", 2.5);
 10         cout << s << s2;
 11 }
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
> Press ENTER or type command to continue In file included from
> main.cpp:2:0: student.h: In function ‘std::ostream&
> operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&)’: student.h:10:9: error: no
> match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘os << "Name\011: "’ student.h:10:9: note:
> candidate is: /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note:
> template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc>
> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
> std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const
> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) student.h:10:33: error:
> passing ‘const Student’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string
> Person::getName()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] student.h:10:38:
> error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’ student.h:11:9: error: no match
> for ‘operator<<’ in ‘os << "Age\011: "’ student.h:11:9: note:
> candidate is: /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note:
> template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc>
> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
> std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const
> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) student.h:11:24: error:
> ‘const class Student’ has no member named ‘getAge’ student.h:11:36:
> error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’ student.h:12:9: error: no match
> for ‘operator<<’ in ‘os << "Major\011: "’ student.h:12:9: note:
> candidate is: /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note:
> template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc>
> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
> std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const
> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) student.h:12:26: error:
> ‘const class Student’ has no member named ‘major’ student.h:12:35:
> error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’ student.h:13:9: error: no match
> for ‘operator<<’ in ‘os << "GPA\011: "’ student.h:13:9: note:
> candidate is: /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note:
> template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc>
> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
> std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const
> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) student.h:13:31: error:
> ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’ main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:10:2: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope

shell returned 1
```

My student.h file:

```
  1 #ifndef STUDENT_H
  2 #define STUDENT_H
  3 
  4 #include <iostream>
  5 #include <string>
  6 #include "person.h"
  7 
  8 class Student : public Person {
  9         friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os,const Student &s){
 10                 os << "Name\t: " << s.getName() << std::endl;
 11                 os << "Age\t: " << s.getAge() << std::endl;
 12                 os << "Major\t: " << s.major << std::endl;
 13                 os << "GPA\t: " << s.gpa << std::endl;
 14                 return os;
 15         }
 16 public:
 17         Student(std::string name, int age, std::string m="undecided", double gpa=0.0) :
 18                 Person::Person(name,age),
 19                 maj(m),
 20                 gpa(gpa)
 21         {}
 22 
 23 
 24 
 25 protected:
 26         double gpa;
 27         std::string maj;
 28 };
 29 #endif
```

I've never seen the compiler have these problems before, anyone seen this before?

BTW, this problem was part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024722/c-error-constructor-parameter) thread where for some reason g++ was complaining
about me using a member variable called "major", also a first time for me, i've never before seen the compiler complaining about a variable name, especially 'major'.
appreciate any help.

Comment: You forgot to type `), s3(`.

Comment: Those error messages are extremely difficult to read. Can you re-paste them without reformatting them (aside from indenting as code)?

Comment: `std::string maj;` but you're doing `<< s.major <<`. Make sure getAge and getName are not private, and are also const. You can at least fix those first. You're also not using endl in main, so this output doesn't appear to match your code.

Comment: You still have these errors from previous thread: `Person::Person` in Student constructor, and in overloaded `<<` implementation you need to rename major to maj.
Since I had your code from previous thread this code works for me after fixing those issues! Your only code missing is person.h. may be you can share that, if error is there.

Comment: Unfortunatey the only thing that got rid of most of the errors was the answer below #include <ostream> explicitly. I tried reinstalling g++ and that didn't work. in the previous thread this: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17130 was pointed out to me. I'm starting to think its the compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never encountered an implementation where `<iostream>` did not bring `<ostream>` with it. And I'm not even sure it's legal for it not to (otherwise the common `"Hello World"` implementation, which only includes `<iostream>` wouldn't even work). But that's the only thing I can fathom would explain that error.

```
#include <ostream>
```

Try adding that to the top of `"student.h"`.

Comment: @ritual_code: Would you mind doing an experiment for me?  Write a basic hello world program, only including iostream: `#include <iostream> int main() { std::cout << "hello world"; }` -- and let me know if it works?  Also, what version of gcc do you have?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I get error: 'cout' is not a member of 'std' =(

Comment: Edit: hey I fixed the issue by completely reinstalling the whole shabang

Comment: For the record: I think it was legal in C++98/03 where (strictly speaking) `<iostream>` wasn't required to include anything (see e.g. http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_issues.html entry for pg 633), hence the usual recommendation to explicitly `#include <ostream>` when using `std::endl`. But in C++11 [`<iostream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) is required to include `<ostream>` (and three other headers) by the Standard (N3337, 27.4 [iostream.objects]). (Still, I think it's “not bad practice” to always explicitly include the “original” header for each symbol.)